# Create continuous function from list

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I have a list of data (measured per day) that I want to use as imput for another equation (say f). The problem is that the input I need for f needs to be a continuous function of time. Is it possible to change my data into a function? I would either like a function that is linear increasing or decreasing between the different timesteps (like the line you get when you use `Joined` in `ListPlot`) or a stepwise function that immediately jumps to another value the next day.

I tried using `Interpolate` but then when I measured 0, I get negative values which is not possible for my measured values.

Hope someone could help me.

Simplified example:

```
tmin=1;
tmax=6;
data = {{1, 3}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 5}, {5, 7}, {6, 10}};
ListPlot[data, AxesLabel -> {"time(day)", "data(mm)"}, Joined -> True]

f = Interpolation[data];
Plot[Evaluate[f[t]], {t, tmin, tmax}]
```

If you evaluate this: the first plot is the result I would prefer for my function, the second plot is not what I want as the values drop below 0.

[image]

Comment: Your variables `tmin` and `tmax` are not defined, can you edit your post so that these have values?

Answer (score 4):

```
data = {{1, 3}, {2, 0}, {3, 0}, {4, 5}, {5, 7}, {6, 10}};
f = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
GraphicsRow[{Plot[f[t], {t, 1, 6}, AxesOrigin -> {-1, -1}], 
             ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, AxesOrigin -> {-1, -1}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! So interpolation order 1 makes the function lineair. Is there also an option to make the interpolation stepwise or is this not possible?

Comment: @user9022 `InterpolationOrder -> 0`